# Suppose I have a field extension $K/F$ and the dimension of $K$ over $F$ is 1. Why can I conclude that $K=F$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have shown that $F\subseteq K$.

I am trying to use the fact that K is a one-dimensional vector space over $F$ to show that $K\subseteq F$. I know that since $K$ is one-dimensional, it has one basis element, say $b$. So any $k \in K$ can be written as $k=fb$ where $f \in F$. Since we are dealing with fields, $f=\frac{k}{b}$. Does this show that $K\subseteq F$? I was told that we can just choose 1 as our basis. But why are we permitted to do this? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: $1=gb$ for some $g\in F$.  Thus $b=1/g$ and $k=fb=f/g\in F$.

Comment: In any $n$-dimensional vector space any set of $n$ linearly independent elements forms a basis. A singleton set $\{b\}$ in a vector space is linearly independent if and only if $b\neq0$. $1\neq0$, so we are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you take $\{b\}\subset K$, which is basis of $K$ over $F$. And By definition a basis is linearly independent set. so here $b\neq 0_K$ must(where $0_K\in K$ is additive identity of $K$).

Now for any $a\in K$ , we have

$$\Rightarrow a.b\in K $$
$$ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\Rightarrow \exists ~ f\in F ~\text{such that}~~ a\cdot b=f\cdot b $$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\Rightarrow a=f\cdot b\cdot b^{-1}=f\in F$$
$$ \Rightarrow K\subset F$$

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense now.